# Большое количество значений в csv файле. Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Всем привет! Есть csv файл с по которому строится график. При выводе самого графика подпись оси х и y нечитаема.
[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

X = []
Y = []

with open('2.csv', 'r') as datafile:
   plotting = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=';')

   for ROWS in plotting:
      X.append(ROWS[0])
      Y.append(ROWS[2])

plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Как это исправить?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе CSV-файл в текстовом виде.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/axes/axes_ticks.html#locators-and-formatters

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вот так:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

X = []
Y = []

with open('2.csv', 'r') as datafile:
    plotting = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=';')

    for ROWS in plotting:
        X.append(ROWS[0])
        Y.append(ROWS[2])

    # Оставляем в списках только каждые вторые значения
    X = X[::2]
    Y = Y[::2]

plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.show()
```

Суть в том, что показываются только каждые вторые значения.

Вы можете подстроить этот код под свои данные, просто меняя число `2`.

Comment: Прошлый вариант был экономнее с точки зрения памяти ))  А тут код короче/проще

Comment: @CrazyElf, и красивее )

Answer (score 2):

Для числовых данных `matplotlib` нормально сам оси размечает. Из этого я делаю вывод, что у вас скорее всего данные в виде текста получаются, попробуйте их преобразовать в `float`:

```py
      X.append(float(ROWS[0]))
      Y.append(float(ROWS[2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы из такого графика
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

получить нормальный
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, используйте ООП-подход matplotlib, а затем установите линейный локатор с нужным вам количеством меток:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4)) # <-- размер изображения в дюймах
ax.plot(X, Y)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(numticks=10)) #<-- здесь
plt.show()
```